# error al cargar un registro de usuario con php

Tags: php, jquery

Saludos, cuando ejecuto un aplicativo en mi PC no tengo errores pero al cargarlo en un hosting al querer hacer un registro me indica el error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method usuarioDao::query() in /home/ufajardo/public_html/archisoft/modelo/dao/usuario/usuariosDao.php on line 81

```
static function  registrarUsuarioDao($apaterno, $amaterno, $nombre, $usuario, $clave, $tipo, $status){
  $datosArray=array($usuario);
  $st=  procesaParametros::PrepareStatement(usuariosSql::validateIfExistsUser(),$datosArray);

  $query=self::query($st);
  //$query=$this->con->query($st);

  if($query->num_rows==0)
  {
    $st = "INSERT INTO usuarios(apaterno, amaterno, nombre, usuario, clave, tipo, status, fRegistro)
    VALUES('$apaterno', '$amaterno', '$nombre', '$usuario', '$clave', '$tipo', '$status', NOW())";

  $query=self::query($st);
    //$query = $this->con->query($st);
    $result = Notification::registeredRecord($query);
  }
  else
  {
    $result = Notification::existsUser();
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Los comentarios son porque cambie ese código por el nuevo, porque me emite este error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/ufajardo/public_html/archisoft/modelo/dao/usuario/usuariosDao.php on line 82

linea 81 es : `$query=self::query($st)`

linea 82 es : `query=$this->con->query($st)`

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos. Por cierto, ¿cuál es el código de `procesaParametros`? - allí debe estar el error.

Comment: Da la impresión de que olvidaste subir al hosting alguno de los archivos que intervienen en el código, o que no están en las mismas rutas y no los está encontrando.

Comment: Recomendaría revises las librerías que estas usando, que estén disponibles en el servidor donde lo quieres montar, así como la versión de PHP sea la misma o al menos compatible con dichas librerías